# Detect changes on every character typed in a TextField QML

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to detect whenever the value in a TextField is altered.
All I see is the `editingFinished()` and `textEdited()` signals which
emits only when the space character,backspace or enter key is pressed.

Tried `Keys.onPressed{}` in the TextField component but didn't work
as expected

Anyone with a better idea to do this?

Comment: have you tried `textChanged`?

Comment: yh, didn't work as expected

Comment: I suggest giving us a minimum reproducible example that shows what you are trying to do and also what you have tried that does not work. All of the signals you have mentioned have always worked for me, so perhaps something else about your code is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be an issue with text not being committed yet to the field. This happens especially on Android devices.

In that case I suggest to test these two solutions:

1. listen on `displayText` property changes with `onDisplayTextChanged` slot, or
2. listen on `preeditText` property changes with `onPreeditTextChanged`

If this is the case and you would like the text be committed after each character, you could do something like:

```
TextField {
  ...
  onPreeditTextChanged: if ( this is android ) Qt.inputMethod.commit() // to avoid Android's uncommited text
}
```

Make sure you do this only on Android (other platforms might double the characters on some keyboards)! It is a little hack. I would first try the `displayText` property.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few hours of trying, I think I found a way which works at least for me using the `contentSizeChanged()` signal

```
TextField {
            id: nameValue
            anchors{
                top: parent.top
                left: parent.left
                right: parent.right
                margins: Style.margin*2
            }

            placeholderText: Style.selectedName
            Material.accent: Style.colorAccent
            font.pixelSize: Style.smallTinyFontSize
            verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter


            onContentSizeChanged: console.log("contentSizeChanged")
            onTextChanged: console.log("TextChanged ")
            onTextEdited: console.log("TextEdited")
            onEditingFinished: console.log("EditingFinished")

            

        }
```

**`Hello World`** typed into the textField with Enter key pressed produces this output at the console

[image]